# How can I reflectively get parameter names for a method included with Java SE?

Tags: java, reflection, parameters, sdkman, paranamer

I'm looking to create some code designed for static imports based on classes in Java SE 8 (specifically, with regards to [threeten-extra#166](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/issues/166)).

As a first pass, I'm automatically generating the Java code for methods based on static factory methods in a specific set of classes.  My hope is to ensure I don't miss anything, reduce the chance for manual error, as well as eliminate repetitive copy/pasting on my part.

I am using the Java reflection API to retrieve `Method` objects for the methods I want to automatically generate code for.  I am then generating a method signature using that `Method` object.

For instance, for the [`LocalDate.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) method, I would want something like this:

```java
public static LocalDate date(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    return LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);
}
```

Of key importance, I want to ensure that my generated Java code signature has parameter names that are the same as those in the JDK.  I know that Java has the ability to get parameter names for a method using [`Parameter.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getName--).  However, the method parameter names are not guaranteed to be present; `.class` files do not store them by default (the `-parameters` option to `javac` will cause them to be included).  For my particular case, the parameter names are in Java, which (for my version at least), does not have them compiled in.

```java
Method method = LocalDate.class
        .getMethod("of", int.class, int.class, int.class);

System.out.printf("public static %s date(%s) {\n",
        method.getReturnType().getSimpleName(),
        Arrays.stream(method.getParameters())
                .map(p -> String.format("%s %s",
                        p.getType().getSimpleName(), p.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.printf("    return %s.%s(%s);\n",
        method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName(),
        method.getName(),
        Arrays.stream(method.getParameters())
                .map(Parameter::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.println("}");
```

**Output:**

```java
public static LocalDate date(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    return LocalDate.of(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}
```

I attempted to use the [Paranamer](https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer) library to read the argument names from the [Java 8 Javadoc](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-doc-downloads.html), but it appears that it does not support the Java 8 Javadoc HTML format ([paranamer#39](https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer/issues/39)).

I am currently using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io) on macOS to manage the version of Java, which is `AdoptOpenJDK` 8.x.  Given that the methods should be identical across Java versions, it would not need to be this specific version of Java 8, though it would have to be *a* version of Java 8.

How can I get the parameter names of a `Method` for built-in Java SE 8 classes in this situation?

Comment: You seem to have pretty conclusively demonstrated that you can't.  If you could, that'd be how.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I mean, maybe there's a way to tell SDKMAN! to use parameters or something that I'm missing, or something I'm missing in Paranamer?  I don't know what I don't know, so I figure it's worth the question.

Comment: What exactly do you gain from those generated methods? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 0):

So long as the method information is stored in the debug table (e.g. not an abstract method), [`BytecodeReadingParanamer`](https://github.com/paul-hammant/paranamer#bytecodereadingparanamer) can be used:

```java
Paranamer paranamer = new CachingParanamer(new BytecodeReadingParanamer());

Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
String[] parameterNames = paranamer.lookupParameterNames(method);

System.out.printf("public static %s date(%s) {\n",
        method.getReturnType().getSimpleName(),
        IntStream.range(0, parameterTypes.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%s %s",
                        parameterTypes[i], parameterNames[i]))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.printf("    return %s.%s(%s);\n",
        method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName(),
        method.getName(),
        String.join(", ", parameterNames));
System.out.println("}");
```